# Center of a split metabelian group of order $p^nq$ is direct summand.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions, metabelian-groups

Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes such that  such that $q \ | \ p-1.$ Suppose we have a group $G$ which is a split extension of the cyclic group $B$ of order $q$ by a finite abelian $p$-group $A.$ Can we say that $Z(G)$ is a direct summand of $G?$

I have tried up to some extent but I am stuck.

Suppose $B = \langle b \rangle.$ Then as $Z(G) \subseteq A,$ we have that all the elements of $A$ which commute with $b$ are the only central elements of $G.$ If $Z(G)$ is non-trivial, then we only need to prove that it is a direct summand of $A.$ For that assume that $A = \langle a_1 \rangle \times \langle a_2 \rangle \times \ldots \times \langle a_n \rangle$ with $o(a_i) = p^i.$ If for some $i,$ $a_i^{p^k}$ commutes with $b,$ then I am trying to prove that $a_i$ also commutes with $b.$

Any comments would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The group A under consideration is abelian.

Comment: What do you mean by and extension of $B$ by $A$? There are two possible interpretations, so you should say which one you mean.

Comment: A is the normal subgroup. So $G = A \rtimes B.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the more general result that if a finite $p'$-group $B$ acts on a finite abelian $p$-group $A$ then $A = C_B(A) \times [B,A]$.

There is a proof in (24.6) of [Aschbacher's book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BprbtnlI6HEC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=group+theory+coprime+action&source=bl&ots=aB23bd0OJD&sig=ACfU3U1Skvpee5QxVUdmU-XU-0-RVcs-Og&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjos8mfu6vnAhVFt3EKHYJgBLwQ6AEwCXoECF8QAQ#v=onepage&q=group%20theory%20coprime%20action&f=false) for example.

Comment: What if $G$ is nilpotent but not abelian?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I overlooked that $A$ is abelian.

Comment: If $A$ is a not necessarily abelian $p$-group then we have $A=C_B(A)[B,A]$ but they can intersect.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Derek Holt